# Слетает анимация кнопки в Unity

Tags: unity3d, анимация, button, ui

После нажатия на кнопку анимация ломается, а после выхода из меню и вовсе застывает - при следующем заходе в меню кнопка не реагирует **визуально** на курсор и нажатия. При создании анимации меняю только цвет и размер кнопки, в аниматоре ничего не меняю.
Видео для наглядности: https://youtu.be/4Ey1gCyF950

В теле методов Pause() и Play() я останавливал и запускал скорость игры строкой `Time.timeScale = 0f;`, после закомментирования, проблема частично решается (но нужно найти другое решение, пауза в игре - штука полезная) - кнопки уже в основном не застываю, но, если во время выхода из меню кнопкой Esc на кнопке находился курсор, то, при следующем открытии меню, кнопка остаётся в положении Highlighted (выделенный) и никак не реагирует, как раньше. Думаю, нужно как-то сбрасывать анимацию (запускать заново) при каждом открытии меню. Как это можно сделать?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class UIMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject PauseMenuUI;
    public bool IsPause = true; //Стоит ли игра на паузе

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (IsPause) Play();
            else Pause();
        }
    }

    private void Pause()
    {
        PauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        //Time.timeScale = 0f;
        IsPause = true;
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        PauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        //Time.timeScale = 1f;
        IsPause = false;
    }

    public void Quit() => Application.Quit();
}
```